# can csharp classes "inherit" the xml documentation like java classes can?

Tags: c#, java, documentation

i'm adding comments to some csharp code, and i'm using the xml language provided by .net (or something). i have an interface, and some implementing classes. i have one method in the interface, and it has a comment. in the implementing classes there is no comment on the implementing method.

when one does it like this in java, javadoc automagically uses the interface comment when generating documentation. however, now that i build my project, i get the warning (transalted from swedish, sorry) "the xml comment for the visible type or member bla.blabla.blablabla() is missing (cs1591)". this is only a warning, so not so bad. but!!! it means no xml file was output, so i can't use sandcastle to generate a chm document file, which is my real goal here.... googling the error coded gave nothing :(

do i really have to copy the method comment to all implementing classes? that's like.... code duplication D: is there no way to get the behavior java offers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way of getting it to happen at XML file generation time, but [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) may well save you from performing the copying manually. I can't say I've used it myself though.

I agree that it would be a valuable feature... particularly if the base class (or interface) documentation changes after the derived classes have been implemented and documented.

Answer (score 1):

You do have to copy the interfaces comments to the implementing class.  Generally this is a good thing as the two comments should ideally be different - my opinion (and practise) on this can be summarised as the following:

**Interface Comments** - Explains what the method/property/etc is supposed/expected to do but should generally not proscribe how any specific implementation should behave

**Implementing Class Comments** - Explains what the method/property/etc actually does and may include some details of how this is done (typically in `<remarks>`)

Comment: i couldn't disagree more. the interface comment should be (abstract) enough for all possible implementations. i think this works pretty well for java's built in api.

Answer (score 1):

[VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) can resolve missing XML comments from implemented interfaces automatically when it generates documentation. Moreover, like GhostDoc, it can also explicitly copy inherited comments to the implementing method. Unlike Sandcastle, it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont know about Java but Sorry you will have to copy the interface's comments in the implemented class. here is no inbuilt way of doing it...

And yeah consider the suggestion given by JonSkeet

Comment: this answer makes me sad :€ (i was gonna put just the sad face, but the application wouldn't let me)

Comment: Sorry ...just try using 3rd party tools as suggested in other answers..    :(